# Saving output in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
import itertools
res = itertools.permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',5) # 5 is the length of the result. 
for i in res: 
   print ''.join(i)
```

I need the result in stead of being printed `print ''.join(i)` to be saved in a .txt file.

I am not familiar with python. Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is very basic; a quick google already points to a tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: All you need is to open a file object and replace `print` with `fileobj.write(''.join(i) + '\n')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file in write mode and just use `fileobject.write` method to write your permutations to the file :

```
with open('file_name.txt','w') as f:
    res = itertools.permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',5) # 5 is the length of the result. 
    for i in res: 
       f.write(''.join(i)+'\n')
```